# What does it mean to change the initializer statements

Tags: java

hi i'm very very new to java and we were asked to write method takes in an array of marks (doubles) as a parameter. The program then computes and prints the total mark, the average mark and the your average mark if the lowest mark is omitted.
Test your program by running it at least 3 times with changing initializer statements.

and i have this code:

```js
public class Excercise7 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[] marks = {10.0, 9.0, 10.0, 10.0, 5.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0};
        computeAverage(marks);
    }

    public static void computeAverage(double[] marks) {
        System.out.print("Marks: ");
        double total = 0.0;
        double lowest = marks[0]; 
        int lowestindex = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < marks.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(marks[i] + " ");
            total += marks[i];
            if (marks[i] < lowest) {
                lowest = marks[i];
                lowestindex = i;
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Total: " + total);
        System.out.println("Average: " + total / marks.length);

        System.out.print("Average omitting lowest: ");
        total = 0.0;
        for (int i = 0; i < marks.length; i++) {
            if (i != lowestindex) {
                total += marks[i];    
            }
        }
        System.out.println(total / (marks.length - 1));
    }
}
```

what does it mean when it says "changing initializer statements"?? do i just change the array of marks to what I want?

Comment: Yep.  Initializers are the values you initially set your variables to.  So the array that follows `marks =` (`{10.0, 9.0, etc.}`) is there to set the initial `marks` values.  Change those to get different behavior.

Comment: [JLS#8.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-VariableInitializer)/[JLS#10.6](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.6) is the super official explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's right, they are asking you to change the values of the array, try not only changing the values for similar ones, try using negatives like -125.68 and not only change the 9 values, try putting much more values in the array.